# Can anyone recommend some books on PDE in $L^p$ space for me?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, partial-differential-equations

I need a book covering $L^p$ theory (is it?) on PDE. Stuff should include: **De Giorgi-Nash-Moser’s iteration**, **Harnack inequalities** and **Schauder estimates** on elliptic/parabolic homogeneous/heterogeneous equations, together with their divergence forms.

I've found Jürgen Jost's *Partial Differential Equations*, whose second half provides more or less I need. Can you recommend some other books providing full details on those topics for me? Thank you~

Comment: Ah, [18-155](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-155-differential-analysis-spring-2004/) and [18-156](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-156-differential-analysis-spring-2004/) on OCW@MIT seem good supplements.

Comment: Haim Brezis' Functional Analysis has some facts about $L^p$ spaces, although maybe not really what you're looking for.

Comment: $L^p$ theory of PDE typically cope with the properties of the solution in $L^p$ space (and Sobolev, Hölder...) of some PDEs, rather than what we learn at undergraduate courses, where solutions are smooth.

Comment: @ziyuang: The first link in your first comment does not work.

Comment: @Jack: Oops... [18-155](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-155-differential-analysis-fall-2004/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference that comes close is also

- Michael E. Taylor: Partial Differential Equations III: Nonlinear Equations. (2nd edition)

See here: [ZMATH](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an:05771970&type=pdf&format=complete)

Answer (score 1):

For the elliptic case the classic reference (and the best I can think of) is "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" by Gilbarg and Trudinger. You'll find a very detailed exposition of Schauder's theory, Harnak inequality and maximum principles, Calderon-Zygmund and so on and so forth. For a good understanding of $L^p$ spaces in general, I agree with Beni Bogosel with the book of Brezis and also recommend Folland's "Real Analysis". It's developed in a slightly more general (and abstract) setting, because instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ he studies arbitrary measure spaces, but the book is an excellent reference in real analysis. Hope I've been helpful...